# save a dataset object to XML

Tags: c#, xml

hi i have this code in which am reading from excel sheet storing it in a dataset and displaying the output, now i want to save whatever i get from ds.GetXm() method in .XML format.(eg : output.xml)

```
daAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
System.Data.DataTable dt=new System.Data.DataTable("ChildElement");
//daAdapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
daAdapter.Fill(dt);
DataSet ds = new DataSet("RootElement");
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
Console.WriteLine(ds.GetXml());
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to Save a string to disc - use the [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamWriter.aspx) class:

```
using System.IO;

....

string xmlString = ds.GetXml();
string path = "Output.xml";
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
{
    writer.Write(xmlString);
}
```

Or if you don't need the string variable and want to be more efficient consider using the [DataSet.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb27k0tf.aspx) method as suggested by Krazibit312. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx):

> *GetXml returns XML as a string, and therefore requires more overhead
>   than WriteXml to write XML to a file.*

Answer (score 2):

Super simple approach:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\myfile.xml", ds.GetXml());
```

From MSDN:

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you need to user StreamWriter object

```
     using System.IO;

     ....
     // Get a StreamWriter object
    StreamWriter xmlDoc = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/FileTest/Testdo.xml"), false);

    // Apply the WriteXml method to write an XML document
     ds.WriteXml(xmlDoc);
     xmlDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//simply 
ds.WriteXML("FileName");
```